Firebase authentication in flutterflow related listview
In flutterflow while testing my app, I get this error - how can I resolve it?

Run mode-only notification: Firestore Security Rules Error on ListView: Missing or insufficient permissions

I have checked all my Firebase settings.
I want to show my dynamic data using listview in flutterflow successfully.
I want to see my dynamic data in flutterflow using listview while testing.

This problem is related to your firebase rules.
Change your firebase rules to something like:
allow read: if true;
if your error stop appearing then your query is trying to access to document for what it doesn't have
